# How to install google analytics on drupal 9?

Tags: drupal-9

I have freshly installed drupal 9.

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/core": "self.version",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "self.version",
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "self.version"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/mink": "^1.8",
        "friends-of-behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.4",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.4",
        "composer/composer": "^2.0.2",
        "drupal/coder": "^8.3.10",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.3",
        "instaclick/php-webdriver": "^1.4.1",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "^1.6.8",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.14 || ^9",
        "phpspec/prophecy": "^1.12",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3.0",
        "symfony/error-handler": "^4.4",
        "justinrainbow/json-schema": "^5.2",
        "symfony/filesystem": "^4.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^4.4",
        "symfony/lock": "^4.4",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.4",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.4 !=4.4.5",
        "easyrdf/easyrdf": "^0.9 || ^1.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "9.99.99",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal9",
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.3.0"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "post-install-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>drupal/drupal</>: This package is meant for core development,",
                "               and not intended to be used for production sites.",
                "               See: https://www.drupal.org/node/3082474"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=red;fg=white>drupal/drupal</>: This package is meant for core development,",
                "               and not intended to be used for production sites.",
                "               See: https://www.drupal.org/node/3082474"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Composer\\": "composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": "Drupal\\Composer\\Composer::ensureComposerVersion",
        "pre-update-cmd": "Drupal\\Composer\\Composer::ensureComposerVersion",
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": [
            "@composer update phpunit/phpunit --with-dependencies --no-progress",
            "@composer require phpspec/prophecy-phpunit:^2 --no-progress --no-suggest"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Drupal\\Composer\\Composer::generateMetapackages"
        ],
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "core"
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "composer/Plugin/ProjectMessage"
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "composer/Plugin/VendorHardening"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have read it is best to use composer for installign modules. So I am trying

```
php8.0 /usr/local/bin/composer  require drupal/google_analytics
Using version ^3.1 for drupal/google_analytics
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/google_analytics
> Drupal\Composer\Composer::ensureComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/google_analytics[dev-3.x, 3.1.0] require drupal/core ^8.8.6|^9.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.6, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.3.x-dev] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but drupal/core[dev-main] from path repo (core) has higher repository priority. The packages with higher priority do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.
    - drupal/google_analytics 3.x-dev is an alias of drupal/google_analytics dev-3.x and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/google_analytics ^3.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/google_analytics[3.1.0, 3.x-dev (alias of dev-3.x)].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

How to understand those errors? Looks like it requires drupal 8 or 9 but i have 9 so why there is a problem? I see there is mentioned priorities, I have read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/repository-priorities.md but I do not get what I need to fix for it to work. Can you tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted vendor directory. Ran composer install. Noticed message after installation

```
drupal/drupal: This package is meant for core development,

               and not intended to be used for production sites.

               See: https://www.drupal.org/node/3082474
```

Packages already clean.

In the link I saw composer command to create new project, so I modified it to this one and tried:

```
composer  -n create-project drupal/recommended-project:* drupal3
```

then followed installation steps https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal

and then tried installing google analytics - and it went without problems.